# Network Scanning: HP Laserjet 2840 & Windows 7 (+ Linux?)

Tags: windows-7, networking, samba, scanner, hp-laserjet

I own a HP Laserjet 2840 multifunction printer.  It's a fabulous device, but on Windows 7 it can't network scan.  HP doesn't seem to support it in anything greater than Vista, and they aren't forth coming with solutions.

I'm curious if anyone else has gotten work arounds to this problem.

One possible avenue for me is that I have an always-on Gentoo server that is configured to see the printer as a fax and printer using hplip.  I have this shared via samba and I can print just fine through samba.  Is there a similar way I can do network scanning?  Anyone know of where I start looking for this?

Comment: Could you make use of Virtual XP mode in Windows 7 instead of the separate Gentoo server?

Comment: So basically you want to know the IP address of your Laserjet?

Comment: @johnthexiii: No, I know the IP address.

In Windows 7, you can't use the 2840 for anything besides printing if it's networked.  I'd like to rectify that.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like many people are having the same problem as you.

There seems to be **no official solution** out there yet. Here are some **workarounds** that might work.

1. **Using a mix of Vista and Windows 7 drivers** ([link](http://www.weston-fl.com/blog/?p=439) with step-by-step tutorial)

   > After several hours we found the solution to install drivers and let the Toolbox fully work so far (push/pull scanning, faxing) using a mix of Vista and Windows 7 drivers.
2. **Downgrade to Win7 32-bit** ([link](http://forums13.itrc.hp.com/service/forums/questionanswer.do?admit=109447627+1284611021489+28353475&threadId=1363960), see 2009/11/9 reply)

   > I was able to install the latest version of the software onto windows 7 32bit. The scanner and all functions work flawlessly. As for 64bit, you're out of luck. I doubt that hp will ever work on it. I ended up downgrading to 32bit so I can get all of the drivers to work with my laptop.
3. **Using Windows Virtual PC XP Mode** ([link](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Windows-7-Beta-and-test/Windows-7-HP-Color-Laser-2840-Driver-Problem/td-p/81129/page/2), see 2010/5/23 reply)

   > ...
   >   This seems to be an easy workaround
   >   It works with ALL the features
4. **Run Installer with Compatibillity Mode** ([link](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Windows-7-Beta-and-test/Windows-7-HP-Color-Laser-2840-Driver-Problem/td-p/81129/page/2), see 2010/5/31 reply)

   > I found way to install this scanner  and finally works for me.
   >   ...
   >   Right click on file, than Property and finally tab "Compatibillity Mode". You need to select Windows Vista SP2 thank click  on Apply.
   >   After the 5 files have been to run in "Compatibille Mode" double click the autorun and follow installation

(I have not tested any of the above methods. Hope these still helps.)

Answer (score 2):

I was successfully able to make this work by doing the following:

1. Right-click the HP Solution Center in the start menu and run as administrator
2. Click Settings at the bottom of the screen
3. Under Scan Settings - Click on "Scan to... Setup"
4. When the dialog box appears, select the options you want and click on "Update the Device"

When it is done, your computer will now be listed in the Scan To list on the printer.

Hope that helps.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

XP was the last Windows versions on which network scan was reported as working reliably for the HP Laserjet 2840.

For Windows versions later than XP, many threads were written about network scan not working, but few if any solutions were found that really worked.

Instead of fighting with network scan, it should be a simple matter to connect the printer to Windows 7 via USB, then share it as a network printer via Windows.

This solution avoids fighting with an old printer driver that is not adapted to Windows 7.